# Wildcard Cell Reference Indexing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, extract, vlookup

Hi I'm trying to find the region code in the below table per licence plates, I am seeking ways to use cell references using wildcard, it does not register and ends up being a string called `*34LB12*` instead of actually being a wildcard index.

Below is the licence plate database called `LICENCEPLATES`

```
Licence Plate   Region (Preferred Result after Index)
34LB12  La Belle
53DF32  De Fritz
```

The reference sheet is on another sheet as such called `REGIONREF`

```
Region Code Region Name
LB  La Belle
LE  Long Ellie
```

I have tried indexing, however, even through hard coding "LE" as such: `=INDEX(REGIONREF!B1:B, MATCH("LE", REGIONREF!A1:A, 1), 1)` it would return "De Fritz".

 I hope this is not too confusing, if need be let me know in which ways I need to clarify :)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 here you go! [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yUd2MOZBdxiFZ4gH6MBdGSB7_A2JRes_AQ9MfdI5lbU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: @TheMaster I am ok with such.

Comment: @emmy ok then..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in B2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d{2}([A-Z]{2})\d{2}"), 
 'Reference Sheet'!A2:B, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

ofc. delete B3

or shorter:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(MID(A2:A, 3, 2), 'Reference Sheet'!A2:B, 2, )))
```

Comment: Just wondering if they were to add another digit (ie. if it became 34LE123) I would have to change the formula as per the length of the digits to the right?

Comment: @emmy instead of `\d{2}` you can use `\d+`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the middle letters through regex:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\d{2}([A-Z]{2})\d{2}")
```

where,

- `\d` stands for digit
- `[A-Z]` stands for any upper case letters
- `{n}` stands for `n` number of previous element
- `()`  is a capture group to extract.

You can then use this inside `VLOOKUP`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),"\d{2}([A-Z]{2})\d{2}"),REGIONREF!A:B,2,0))
```